# Reading large result set from Mongo - performance issue

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

Faced performance issue where reading several thousands. We have RoR application where we read data stored in Mongo. We use Monogid. Each stored documents contain 17 fields (15 float, and 2 as integer). We execute query which supported by index. Cursor return very fast (<50ms) but reading all documents take more then 500ms. 
To find bottleneck we run the same query in Mongo Shell and query took <50ms to complete and iterate overall rows in result set. We have tested Mongo Ruby Driver and query take 250ms to complete. The same result we have if using Moped. Finally we have wrote c++ app which use mongo c++ driver and time to iterate over all result set - <20ms. But if we unzip received BSON object (to output it to console) time rise up to 120ms.
Does extraction from BSON take that much time?

Comment: It would take some more fine-tuned digging to confirm but, yes, it sounds like the difference is in the language/driver performance between C++ and the shell (based on a C++ driver) and Ruby. I'm not sure what you mean by unzipping the received BSON object.

Comment: @wdberkeley Creating Ruby object (actual object or hash) from received binary data (BSON.deserialized) .